# How to create a Datomic partition without using db.part

Tags: datomic

In the official docs for Datomic (http://docs.datomic.com/schema.html) under the heading 'Creating new partitions' it says that a new partition (communities) can be created like this:

```
{:db/id #db/id[:db.part/db]
 :db/ident :communities}
```

Here the ':communities' is not written as 'db.part/communities'

I can not install a new partition this way. For me it has to be with the leading 'db.part/'. Is the documentation wrong, or am I not seeing the bigger picture?

Comment: Can you clarify what you have tried and what went wrong?

Comment: Btw, you're missing the `:db.install/partition attribute`

Answer (score 1):

If you read further in the documentation, you'll see that you're missing another datom required for that transaction (labeled with *"Here is the complete transaction..."*). That datom is (with user assigned tempid as -1 optional):

```
[:db/add :db.part/db :db.install/partition #db/id[:db.part/db -1]]
```

Anything transacted with a tempid that resolves to the system partition (`:db.part/db`) must also include a datom marking the installation, as with `:db.install/partition` and `:db.install/attribute` (the reverse ref version for attribute included in the map is more common).

Transacting the full example from the docs works fine:

```
(def tx [{:db/id #db/id[:db.part/db -1]
          :db/ident :communities}
         [:db/add :db.part/db :db.install/partition #db/id[:db.part/db -1]]])
@(d/transact conn tx)
;; returns successful tx map
```